Use OEMConfig for Device Admin, KIOSK APP
I am looking how to use OEMConfig for my Device Admin app. Let's take lenovo as an example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.oemconfig.rel
App has below restrictions defined:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <restriction android:description="@string/connectivity_description" android:title="@string/connectivity_title" android:key="profileConnectivity" android:restrictionType="7">
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_sim_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_sim" android:key="profileConnectivityDisableSIM" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/set_default_apn_description" android:title="@string/set_default_apn" android:key="profileConnectivitySetDefaultAPN" android:defaultValue="" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_apn_settings_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_apn_settings" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowAPNSettings" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_mobile_data_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_mobile_data" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableMobileData" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_mobile_data_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_mobile_data" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowMobileData" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:title="@string/add_wifi_ssid" android:key="profileConnectivityAddWifiSSID" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/add_wifi_ssid_description" android:title="@string/add_wifi_ssid_ssid" android:key="profileConnectivityAddWifiSSID_ssid" android:defaultValue="" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/add_wifi_password_description" android:title="@string/add_wifi_ssid_password" android:key="profileConnectivityAddWifiSSID_password" android:defaultValue="" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/add_wifi_type_description" android:title="@string/add_wifi_ssid_type" android:key="profileConnectivityAddWifiSSID_type" android:defaultValue="0" android:restrictionType="integer"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/add_wifi_connect_description" android:title="@string/add_wifi_ssid_connect" android:key="profileConnectivityAddWifiSSID_connect" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/enable_wifi_description" android:title="@string/enable_wifi_title" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableWifi" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/allow_wifi_configuration_change_description" android:title="@string/allow_wifi_configuration_change_title" android:key="profileConnectivityWifiConfigChange" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_wifi_ap_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_wifi_ap" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowWifiAP" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/enable_wifi_hotspot_description" android:title="@string/enable_wifi_hotspot_title" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableWifiHotspot" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/allow_wifi_hotspot_change_description" android:title="@string/allow_wifi_hotspot_change_title" android:key="profileConnectivityWifiHotspotConfigChange" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_wifi_direct_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_wifi_direct" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowWifiDirect" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_wifi_captive_captive_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_wifi_captive_captive" android:key="profileConnectivityDisableWifiCaptive" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:title="@string/set_http_proxy" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/set_http_proxy_host_description" android:title="@string/set_http_proxy_host" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy_host" android:defaultValue="" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/set_http_proxy_port_description" android:title="@string/set_http_proxy_port" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy_port" android:defaultValue="0" android:restrictionType="integer"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/set_http_proxy_bypassarray_description" android:title="@string/set_http_proxy_bypassarray" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy_bypasslist" android:restrictionType="8">
            <restriction android:title="@string/set_http_proxy_bypassitem" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy_bypasslist_array" android:restrictionType="7">
                <restriction android:title="@string/set_http_proxy_bypassitem" android:key="profileConnectivitySetHttpProxy_bypasslist_string" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            </restriction>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:entries="@array/entries_usb" android:title="@string/set_current_usb_mode" android:key="profileConnectivitySetUSBMode" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/entries_usb_values" android:restrictionType="choice"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_usb_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_usb" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowUSB" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_usb_tethering_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_usb_tethering" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableUSBTethering" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_usb_tethering_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_usb_tethering" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowUSBTethering" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/enable_bluetooth_description" android:title="@string/enable_bluetooth_title" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableBluetooth" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/allow_bluetooth_configuration_change_description" android:title="@string/allow_bluetooth_configuration_change_title" android:key="profileConnectivityBluetoothConfigChange" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_bluetooth_tethering_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_bluetooth_tethering" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableBluetoothTethering" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_bluetooth_tethering_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_bluetooth_tethering" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowBluetoothTethering" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:entries="@array/entries_locationmode" android:title="@string/set_location_mode" android:key="profileConnectivitySetLocationMode" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/entries_locationmode_values" android:restrictionType="choice"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_location_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_location" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableLocation" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_location_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_location" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowLocation" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_enable_sd_card_description" android:title="@string/disable_enable_sd_card" android:key="profileConnectivityDisableSDCard" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/on_off_flight_mode_description" android:title="@string/on_off_flight_mode" android:key="profileConnectivityEnableAirPlaneMode" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disallow_allow_flight_mode_description" android:title="@string/disallow_allow_flight_mode" android:key="profileConnectivityDisallowAirPlaneMode" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:title="@string/create_apn_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateApn" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:title="@string/create_apn_apn_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateApn_apnName" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:title="@string/create_apn_entry_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateApn_entryName" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:title="@string/create_apn_numeric_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateApn_numeric" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/set_prefer_apn_description" android:title="@string/set_prefer_apn_title" android:key="profileConnectivitySetPreferApn" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/set_prefer_apn_name_description" android:title="@string/set_prefer_apn_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivitySetPreferApn_name" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/set_prefer_apn_numeric_description" android:title="@string/set_prefer_apn_numeric_title" android:key="profileConnectivitySetPreferApn_numeric" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/delete_apn_description" android:title="@string/delete_apn_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDeleteApn" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/delete_apn_name_description" android:title="@string/delete_apn_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDeleteApn_name" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/delete_apn_numeric_description" android:title="@string/delete_apn_numeric_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDeleteApn_numeric" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/create_vpn_description" android:title="@string/create_vpn_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateVpn" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/create_vpn_name_description" android:title="@string/create_vpn_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateVpn_name" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/create_vpn_server_description" android:title="@string/create_vpn_server_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateVpn_server" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/create_vpn_username_description" android:title="@string/create_vpn_username_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateVpn_username" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/create_vpn_password_description" android:title="@string/create_vpn_password_title" android:key="profileConnectivityCreateVpn_password" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/delete_vpn_description" android:title="@string/delete_vpn_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDeleteVpn" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/delete_vpn_name_description" android:title="@string/delete_vpn_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDeleteVpn_name" android:restrictionType="string"/>
        </restriction>
        <restriction android:description="@string/disable_random_mac_description" android:title="@string/disable_random_mac_title" android:key="profileConnectivityDisableRandomMac" android:defaultValue="false" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        <restriction android:description="@string/modify_ap_config_description" android:title="@string/modify_ap_config_title" android:key="profileConnectivityModifyApConfig" android:restrictionType="7">
            <restriction android:description="@string/modify_ap_config_ap_name_description" android:title="@string/modify_ap_config_ap_name_title" android:key="profileConnectivityModifyApConfig_apName" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/modify_ap_config_password_description" android:title="@string/modify_ap_config_password_title" android:key="profileConnectivityModifyApConfig_password" android:restrictionType="string"/>
            <restriction android:description="@string/modify_ap_config_is5GHZ_description" android:title="@string/modify_ap_config_is5GHZ_title" android:key="profileConnectivityModifyApConfig_is5GHZ" android:restrictionType="bool"/>
        </restriction>
    </restriction>
</restrictions>

Let's say I wish to disable sim using profileConnectivityDisableSIM. How to do it? My snippet that doesn't seem to work:
    private static void setOemRestrictions(DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager, ComponentName adminComponentName) {
        Bundle lenovoOemBundle = new Bundle();

        Bundle connectivityLenovoOemBundle = new Bundle();
        connectivityLenovoOemBundle.putBoolean("profileConnectivityDisableSIM", true);
        lenovoOemBundle.putBundle("profileConnectivity", connectivityLenovoOemBundle);

        devicePolicyManager.setApplicationRestrictions(adminComponentName, "com.lenovo.oemconfig.rel", lenovoOemBundle);

        final String[] packages = {activity.getPackageName(), "com.lenovo.oemconfig.rel"};
        devicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(adminComponentName, packages);
    }

What is incorrect?
